# Display records on next row in table

Tags: visualforce, html, table

Hi i want to display a list in table in following way..

```
rec1   rec2   rec3   rec4

rec5   rec6   rec7   rec8

rec9   rec19  rec11  rec12
```

Where the records are displayed on the next row when a certain amount of columns has been reached.

The code I'm currently using is:

```
<head>
    <script> ul { columns: 2; -webkit-columns: 2; -mox-columns: 2; } </script> 
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <ul class="columns" data-columns="2" style="column-count:2">
            <li>List 1</li>
            <li>List 2</li>
            <li>List 3</li>
            <li>List 4</li>
            <li>List 5</li>
            <li>List 6</li>
            <li>List 7</li>
            <li>List 8</li>
            <li>List 9</li>
            <li>List 10</li>
            <li>List 11</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you show us some of the code you are currently using?

Comment: <head><script>
 ul {
    columns: 2;
    -webkit-columns: 2;
    -mox-columns: 2;
     }
      </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <ul class="columns" data-columns="2" style="column-count:2">
                <li>List 1</li>
                <li>List 2</li>
                <li>List 3</li>
                <li>List 4</li>
                <li>List 5</li>
                <li>List 6</li>
                <li>List 7</li>
                <li>List 8</li>
                <li>List 9</li>
                <li>List 10</li>
                <li>List 11</li>
            </ul></div></body>

Comment: I don't think there is an easy way to do this using an `<ul>`. Can you use an HTML table instead of an unordered list?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you could do is loop over your records and write regular HTML. Count the rows you wish to show, and then check each cycle with a remainder division (where the divisor is the amount of columns you want) if you need to write a new tablerow.

I was a bit bored, and decided to do this:

**My Controller/Extension:**

```
public with sharing class Tester {
public List<String> records{get;set;}

public Tester()
{
    records = new List<String>();
    records.add('rec1');
    records.add('rec2');
    records.add('rec3');
    records.add('rec4');
    records.add('rec5');
    records.add('rec6');
    records.add('rec7');
    records.add('rec8');
    records.add('rec9');
    records.add('rec10');
    records.add('rec11');
    records.add('rec12');
}
}
```

**Visualforce Page:**

```
<apex:page controller="Tester">
    <apex:variable value="{!1}" var="counter"/>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <apex:repeat value="{!records}" var="rec">
                <td>{!rec}</td>
                <apex:outputText rendered="{!AND((MOD(counter, 4) == 0), (counter < records.size))}" value="</tr><tr>" escape="false"/>
                <apex:variable var="counter" value="{!counter + 1}"/>
            </apex:repeat>
        </tr>
    </table>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: No it's not! Good luck using panelGrid with repeat for example (second paragraph in the help). It'll have it's uses but yours is way more flexible.

Comment: If I were rendering the output to PDF, this would be my preferred solution to this situation to allow flexibility of formatting, etc. Nice job PJC!

Answer (score 5):

Sounds like a job for [`<apex:panelGrid>`](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_panelGrid.htm)?

```
<apex:page>
    <apex:panelGrid columns="3" id="theGrid">
        <apex:outputText value="First" id="theFirst"/>
        <apex:outputText value="Second" id="theSecond"/>
        <apex:outputText value="Third" id="theThird"/>
        <apex:outputText value="Fourth" id="theFourth"/>
    </apex:panelGrid>
</apex:page>
```

Will cause the last item to "overflow" to next row.

Bit less mess than hand-crafting `<tr>`s and figuring out when to close them with `escape="false"`...

Comment: Haha, this is awesome, didn't know this component existed, now i'll have to downvote my own answer :)

Comment: Hi @PJC! Leave it, there probably are some situations when you want such "few things in a row but it can't be a table" and then your technique with putting separator of some kind (close `ul` and make new one, put `<br/>` etc) might be still a valid solution...